system Requirements for the DeepSeek-Coder-V2-Instruct
I want to know the Windows system requirements of the below versions of DeepSeek Coder V2 (236 TB and 21B AP). https://github.com/deepseek-ai/DeepSeek-Coder-V2/tree/main. I am using the system with specifications mentioned below:

Device Name: ###
Full Device Name: #####
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz (4 cores, 8 threads)
Installed RAM: 16.0 GB (15.3 GB usable)
Device ID: ###
Product ID: ###
SystemnType: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Integrated GPU: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
Dedicated GPU: NVIDIA T500

Can you also suggest me which version of DeepSeek Coder V2 I can use based on the system I have.

I found the information on my question. In order to use the Deepseek coder v2 236b in local computer (local server), 8 GPUs (each with 80 GB RAM) should be available.
Source: Deepseek coder V2 Github
